# Match pandas index to a list and replace with the item in the list

Tags: pandas

The strings in `common_samples` (except the last character) may match to `mrna_raw.index`. If matches are found, append/replace that missing character.

```
import pandas as pd

common_samples = pd.Index(set(kirp_meth.columns)&set(mrna_norm.index)&set(kirp_mut.index)&set(kirp_cna.index)&set(kirp_protein.index)).sort_values()

if [x[:-1] for x in common_samples] == mrna_raw.index:
    mrna_raw.index + [x[-1:] for x in common_samples]

Traceback:

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [39], in <cell line: 2>()
      1 # Append last digit to `mrna_raw`
----> 2 if [x[:-1] for x in common_samples] == mrna_raw.index:
      3     mrna_raw.index + [x[-1:] for x in common_samples]

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/common.py:81, in _unpack_zerodim_and_defer.<locals>.new_method(self, other)
     77             return NotImplemented
     79 other = item_from_zerodim(other)
---> 81 return method(self, other)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/arraylike.py:40, in OpsMixin.__eq__(self, other)
     38 @unpack_zerodim_and_defer("__eq__")
     39 def __eq__(self, other):
---> 40     return self._cmp_method(other, operator.eq)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py:6776, in Index._cmp_method(self, other, op)
   6773 elif is_object_dtype(self.dtype) and not isinstance(self, ABCMultiIndex):
   6774     # don't pass MultiIndex
   6775     with np.errstate(all="ignore"):
-> 6776         result = ops.comp_method_OBJECT_ARRAY(op, self._values, other)
   6778 else:
   6779     with np.errstate(all="ignore"):

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py:79, in comp_method_OBJECT_ARRAY(op, x, y)
     76         y = y._values
     78     if x.shape != y.shape:
---> 79         raise ValueError("Shapes must match", x.shape, y.shape)
     80     result = libops.vec_compare(x.ravel(), y.ravel(), op)
     81 else:

ValueError: ('Shapes must match', (323,), (202,))
```

Example:

`common_samples`

```
Index(['TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A', 'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A', 'TCGA-2Z-A9J3-01A'],
      dtype='object', length=3)
```

`mrna_raw.index`

```
Index(['TCGA-2K-A9WE-01', 'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01', 'TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01',
       'TCGA-2Z-A9J3-01'],
      dtype='object', length=4)
```

Dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame({'A1BG': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01': 391.94,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01': 68.91,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01': 37.0},
 'A1CF': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01': 8.0,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01': 75.0,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01': 14.0},
 'A2BP1': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01': 1.0,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01': 0.0,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01': 0.0}})
```

Expected output (i.e., new `mrna_raw.index`):

`'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A', 'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A', 'TCGA-2Z-A9J3-01A'`

Comment: The expected output is equal to 'common_samples'. Are you sure this is right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you right:

```
mrna_raw = pd.DataFrame({'A1BG': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01': 391.94,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01': 68.91,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01': 37.0},
 'A1CF': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01': 8.0,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01': 75.0,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01': 14.0},
 'A2BP1': {'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01': 1.0,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01': 0.0,
  'TCGA-2Z-A9J2-01': 0.0}})

common_samples = ['TCGA-2K-A9WE-01A', 'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01A', 'TCGA-2Z-A9J3-01A']
common_samples_trimmed = [item[:-1] for item in common_samples]
new_list = []
old_list = []

for item in mrna_raw.index:
    if (item in common_samples_trimmed):
        indx = common_samples_trimmed.index(item)
        new_list.append(common_samples[indx])
        old_list.append(item)
mrna_raw = mrna_raw.loc[old_list]
mrna_raw.index = new_list
```

Comment: I want to rename the mrna_raw.index with the `new_list` items if and only if the original `mrna_raw.index` matches `common_samples_trimmed`.

Comment: Yes. This is what: 'if (item in common_samples_trimmed):' does

Comment: Isnt' it supposed to be `for item in mrna_raw.index`?

Comment: I called it the list mrna_raw without the reserved word '.index.'. Run my code and see that it works

Comment: The `new_list` returns a correct string but it doesn't replace the `mrna_raw.index` with the `new_list`.

Comment: Then just add: mrna_raw = new_list

Comment: I tried `mrna_raw.index = new_list` inside and outside the for-loop but it returned an error `ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 323 elements, new values have 0 elements`.

Comment: What is the content of your original: mrna_raw?

Comment: I added the info to the question. It's under `Dataframe`

Comment: See updated code. If you run it you will get an error. This is because it is not finding one of the indexes in the common-samples list and therefore returns 2 indexes instead of four

Comment: I want to avoid the error by only retaining rows of `mrna_raw` where the index match with `common_samples_trimmed`

Comment: Now I understand :-) See updated code